# How to Rewrite the query

Tags: mysql

I need to rewrite the query in an optimized way , can any one help me in doing this so ?

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(START_TIME) > 30;
```

`start_time` column is `date time not null`

Comment: Whats wrong with the current query?

Comment: Subtract `30` days from `NOW()` and check if it's more than `START_TIME`. Then make sure there is a single `START_TIME` index (or an index that covers it in a left most part)

Comment: @Gillian Lo Wong: it's obvious - `START_TIME` column is used in a function call

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to delete records older than 30 days, this is the most efficient `WHERE` I could think of:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE START_TIME < NOW - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: "this should be very fast" --- I wouldn't say so, ever :-)

Comment: "this should be fast enough" --- isn't better :-) "Fast enough" for what?

Comment: This rather assumes that there is an index on `START_TIME`, which is not clear from the question.

Comment: @eggyal: even if there is an index, it doesn't mean it won't cause a full table scan

Comment: @zerkms: this often worked for me without requiring a full scan.

Comment: Hi all

Thanks for the answers.

Using the above examples i rewrote the query in the below format , please check and let me know .

By looking at the below query you may understand basically what is my requirement

select * FROM test WHERE START_TIME < str_to_date(CONCAT(date_format((NOW()-INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'),'00:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');

and this query is using index.

Comment: @Salman A: imagine a table with 100k rows **all of them** dated a year ago. If you try that - you'll see a full scan.

Comment: @sai: if you want to chop off the time portion simply use `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `NOW()`.

Comment: @zerkms: if you're selecting 99% records then yes, MySQL does not need to use an index.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM TEST WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Start_time))>30
FROM TABLE1
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: It won't. `Start_time` is still used in a function call

Comment: Hi all

Thanks for the answers.

Using the above examples i rewrote the query in the below format , please check and let me know .

By looking at the below query you may understand basically what is my requirement

select * FROM test WHERE START_TIME < str_to_date(CONCAT(date_format((NOW()-INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'),'00:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');

and this query is using index.